# Can't make jQuery ajax call last more than 4 minutes, even with timeout set, with net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, timeout

I have a node.js server running, and I am making a series of ajax calls to that server via jquery.  One of the ajax calls is expected to take around 5 minutes to complete.  I have found that when making the call, it always times out at exactly 4 minutes, with the error 'net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.  I have seen questions such as the following: [ajax net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after waiting for response for 2 mins - node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910084/ajax-neterr-empty-response-after-waiting-for-response-for-2-mins-node-js-ser) but this occurs regardless if I've set the timeout param (either as 0, which means 'no timeout' in jquery, or if I set it as something greater than 4 minutes - for example 300000 which is 5 minutes.) . It happens at 4 minutes on the dot, every single time.

Does anyone have any ideas why this occurs?  Is there an upper limit on ajax jquery calls, how long they can take - regardless of what timeout parameter is set?

Here is the code where the ajax call is being made:

(this try block is in a function which serves the purpose of making an ajax call to a particular URL. `url`, `jsonToSend`, and `timeout` are all parameters to this function.  (specifically, `timeout` is an int, a number **in milliseconds**, to wait before the call times out)

```
try {
    var ajaxCallConfig = {                                                                   
        method: action,                                                                      
        url: url,
        data: jsonToSend,
        contentType: "application/json",                                                     
        success: function (ret) {
            deferred.resolve(ret);                                                           
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            // I ALWAYS end up in this block, with a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE being thrown, when I call this function to the long running api endpoint
            console.log("Error on Ajax call to " + url + "; json " +                         
                JSON.stringify(jsonToSend) +
                ";  text status: " + textStatus +
                "; error thrown: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));                                   
            // check if it was a timeout
            if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                // some error handling my server does specific to timeouts...
                // left it out as it's not relevant... 
                // note : never hit this block, when the net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE issue happens. (when i call the long-running api)
                // but I hit this block if i give some dummy low value to the 'timeout' param to force a timeout.                                                                      
            }
            else { 
                if (xhr.responseJSON) { 
                    // under this case, server sent the response and set                     
                    // the status code
                    deferred.reject(xhr.responseJSON);                                       
                }
                else { 
                    // under this case, the error status is not set by                       
                    // server, it may due to other reasons                                   
                    deferred.reject("Connection Error: " +
                        " Connection to server cannot be established");                      
                }                                                                            
            }                                                                                
        }                                                                                    
    }; 
    if (typeof timeout !== 'undefined') { 
        console.log("set a timeout of " + timeout);  // timeout is definitely being set, as I see this in console logs                                       
        ajaxCallConfig.timeout = timeout;  // timeout attr does work , because when I try this with a very low number, say 300, it times out immediately                                                  
    }
    jQuery.ajax(ajaxCallConfig);  // here we're making the ajax call                                                           
}
```

// catch block, rest of function..

Comment: The timeout is dependent on the server. If the server you are trying to reach has a timeout, you can't really go around it.
If it is your server, how to increase the timeout will be in the docs of whatever web server you are using (Express, Express+Nginx, Apache, etc.)

Comment: MadWard - thanks!  I did not realize that.  It is a simple nodejs server, I'll investigate right away.

Comment: Oddly enough, Node's default Http timeout is said to be 2 minutes in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback)

Comment: @MadWard - oh man... you saved the day here... adjusting my nodejs server's timeout param to 600000 (10 minutes), absolutely did the trick.  Everything works perfect now!  Can not thank you enough... for anyone else who ever hits it -  where my nodejs server is being defined:

var server = app.listen(serverPort, function () {
        var host = server.address().address                                                          
        var port = server.address().port
    });
    server.timeout = 600000;  // fixed it

Comment: No worries, wouldn't want you hitting your head for hours on something that is an easy fix!

Answer (score 3):

As answered by @MadWard - I wish to post this here in case anyone else ever stumbles on this!  The nodejs server which was running (Which ajax was sending the ajax call to), seemed to have a default timeout of 4 minutes.  So no matter what timeout I specified to jquery for making the call, if that call took more than 4 minutes, the server itself would error out.

Since this is my own server, I was able to solve this by simply increasing the 'timeout' attribute of the nodejs server itself.    Here's an example (from the file where the nodejs server is being defined):

```
var server = app.listen(serverPort, function () {                                                
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port                                                             
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)                             
}); 
server.timeout = 600000; // this was not set before.  The default appeared to have been 4 minutes. Setting this fixed it!  (NOTE this should be in milliseconds - so this is 10 minutes!)
```